# Вставка в БД (в поле "json") через htmlspecialchars

Tags: база-данных, json, htmlspecialchars

Добрый день!
В БД "cars", в таблице "marki" есть поле "json".
Я туда вставлял Название марок через "json_encode".
Теперь туда же надо вставлять названия марок через "htmlspecialchars".
Чтобы также отображалось!
Но вставляет пустую строку. Как исправить код?

Код у меня такой:

```
$marka=@$_POST['marka_name'];

$far=array('marka_name'=>$marka);

$json1=htmlspecialchars($far);

$sql="INSERT INTO marki (json)value('$json1')";
$res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
if($res){
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
```

?>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось ПРОСТО! Ввод в БД таков:

```
if($target=="add_marka"){
    $marka=@$_POST['marka_name'];
    $far=array('marka_name'=>$marka);
    // normJsonStr - функция руссификации для PHP ранее 5.4
    $json=normJsonStr(json_encode($far)); 
    $json1=htmlspecialchars($json);
    $sql="INSERT INTO marki (json)value('$json1')";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    if($res){
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";}
    }
}
```

Вывод в браузер будет наоборот: сперва `htmlspecialchars_decode`, а уже потом `json_decode`!
Надеюсь этот код поможет коллегам!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы все равно используете mysqli(что правильно), то для создания запроса надо делать так

```
$db=new mysqli(...);
$sql="INSERT INTO marki (json)value(?)";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$json1);
$stmt->execute();
```